# Copy data to a specific cell range on another worksheet in excel

Tags: vba, excel

HI I have this code which works well to copy and append data to a separate worksheet however I want it to paste to a specific cell range in the destination sheet, how do I go about ammending it?

```
Sub SummurizeSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Summary").Activate

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
            ws.Range("D2:D6, D8:D15").Copy
            Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify this line so that it refers to the desired Worksheet and cell(s) address:

```
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

For example, this puts it on a worksheet named "Another Sheet Name" and in column F, instead of column C:

```
Worksheets("Another Sheet Name").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Update: You are using a somewhat dynamic range already, in conjunction with the `Offset` method. If you have trouble getting this to paste the values to the desired location, let me know what that location is and I can give more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I want the data to paste into E1, at present it vacates row 1 I am not sure why, I need to easily edit this for subsequent workbooks that all have 12 worksheets to summarise into named columns hope this makes sense

Comment: The `.Offset` method is taking the destination range and "moving" it down to `E2`.  You should be able to just remove `.Offset(1, 0)` and I think that should do it.

Comment: Thanks David you were correct now working and i can change the rows.count for subsequent sheets to place the results. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, please do mark this answer "Accepted" if it's solved your question :)